# Change IP of DB server SP 2013 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sql-server

I have SharePoint Foundation 2013 with the WFE on one server and the db on another.  I need to change the SQL server IP address.  What's the process of doing this correctly?

Comment: are you using the SQL alias?

Comment: No, I am not...

Comment: check this one http://www.edinkapic.com/2010/05/sharepoint-configuration-database-ip.html

Comment: The reason why I posted the questions is because these two answers are what I've found.  One says you have to run all sorts of commands (stsadm/etc) and the others say just wait for DNS to propagate.

Comment: In your case, it is only SQL IP change then wait for the IP address updated for the server.

Answer (score 2):

Given you did not reference your SQL Server by IP address when building the farm, the process is straight forward. Update the IP address. If you used the SQL Server hostname (computer name) on the farm, just wait for the IP address to update in DNS. If you used a custom A record, update the custom A record to point to the new IP address.

Comment: If that is the case, then I will leave this post open until next week when I am able to make this change and will mention the results then.